# How do I filter items using numpy.delete? (working for some but not others)

Tags: python, numpy, indices

My goal is to first filter out all values of 0. in radio flux and the corresponding (same index) data in Right Ascension (RA) and Distance (reliant on redshift/z), then divide those arrays into two groups, radio loud (radioflux > 1) and radio quiet (radioflux <= 1). The code works fine until I try deleting the radio quiet quasars indices from the RA and Distance arrays to get the remaining radio loud ones, and vice versa to get radio quiet ones. These are the values I get for when I check to see how many values in an array there are:

- Radio Flux:  166583
- Radio Cut:  12464
- Radio Loud:  239
- Radio Quiet:  12225
- Distance Cut:  12464
- Angle Cut:  12464
- Distance Loud:  12120
- Distance Quiet:  12424
- Angle Loud:  12120
- Angle Quiet:  12424

It should be:

- Radio Flux:  166583
- Radio Cut:  12464
- Radio Loud:  239
- Radio Quiet:  12225
- Distance Cut:  12464
- Angle Cut:  12464
- Distance Loud:  239
- Distance Quiet:  12225
- Angle Loud:  239
- Angle Quiet:  12225

Snippet of my code: (All of the used variables/array names have already been defined previously)

```
values = radioflux
searchval = 0
searchvalquietloud = 1


indices = np.where(values == searchval)[0]
radiocut = np.delete(radioflux,indices)


quiet = np.where(values <= searchvalquietloud)[0]
radioloud = np.delete(radiocut,quiet)

loud = np.where(values > searchvalquietloud)[0]
radioquiet = np.delete(radiocut,loud)

distance = np.multiply(redshift,dist)
angle = np.multiply(ra,radians)

distancecut = np.delete(distance,indices)
anglecut = np.delete(angle,indices)

distancequiet = np.delete(distancecut,radioloud)
distanceloud = np.delete(distancecut,radioquiet)

anglequiet = np.delete(anglecut,radioloud)
angleloud = np.delete(anglecut,radioquiet)
```

Comment: Aside: if you're working with real labelled data and you want to take portions of it and compute statistics, etc., you're much better off using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) than bare numpy.

Comment: These are 1-d arrays? While I've never used Pandas, I've scanned the docs and agree with @DSM.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of big bugs in the code posted:

1. You use `np.where` to find indices on your original `radioflux` array, but then use those indices to remove elements from `radiocut`, which is a filtered version of `radioflux`. The fact that you are not getting an `IndexError` points to this being a transcription error, but you may want to double check.
2. When filtering the `distancecut` and `anglecut` arrays, you are not using the `loud` and `quiet` arrays, which hold the indices, but `radioloud` and `radioquiet`, which hold radio flux values.

Aside from that, the canonical way of doing this with numpy would be to use boolean indexing, and would look something like this:

```
cut_mask = values != searchval
radiocut = radioflux[cut_mask]
loud_mask = radiocut > searchvalquietloud
quiet_mask = ~loud_mask
radioloud = radiocut[loud_mask]
radioquiet = radiocut[quiet_mask]
```

And you would then process your other two arrays as:

```
distancecut = distance[cut_mask]
distanceloud = distancecut[loud_mask]
distancequiet = distancecut[quiet_mask]
```

and similarly for `angle`.